# PUT vs. POST when creating multiple resources that already have IDs

Tags: rest, http

I'm building an API where the majority of endpoints accept and return multiple resources. I'm having trouble determining whether to use POST or PUT requests.

In my situation, resources are always created and identified outside of the API using UUIDs for identifiers. Since the resources already exist and are already identified, a PUT request seems appropriate. However, it would be impractical to include the UUID of each resource in the URI (the UUIDs are very long and there could be many resources in a single request).

A POST request also seems appropriate because even though the resource is already identified with an ID, it does not yet exist in *our* database. Also, with POST requests, there is no expectation of having the IDs in the URI.

Which would be the correct HTTP verb to use in this situation?

```
 PUT /resources/1,2,3 ---> Impractical due to the number of resources per request  
 PUT /resources ---------> More practical but lacks IDs in the URI
POST /resources ---------> Possibly inaccurate verb since resource is already identified
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your three choices, as I see them, are:

0. Use `PUT /resources/1`, then `PUT /resources/2`, then `PUT /resources 3`. This is the "as designed" approach. It does result in 3 calls instead of 1, but lets you leverage the benefits of using `PUT`.
1. Use `POST /resources`, with the body of the `POST` containing all details on all the resources going up to the server, including the id. The server can create the resource from the id in the body. You lose the benefits of `PUT`, but save on wire traffic.
2. Use `PATCH /resources`, with the body of the `PATCH` containing all details on the resources to be created. This really only works if you're using JSON, since patch semantics for XML are iffy at best. The semantics are described in [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).

It is generally not suggested to perform a request on multiple ids. If you call `PUT /resources`, semantically you're saying that you're replacing the contents of `/resources` with the body you just sent up, which is not what you intend.

I would suggest the first approach unless you have a proven reason to avoid it (tested and have a performance issue). In that case, I'd seriously consider `PATCH` over `POST`.

Comment: In your suggested option 2, what do you return? Normally a POST would return a 201 and the location header indicating the created resource. What would you expect to be returned when doing a POST of several resources?

Comment: @AlexWhite Your only option would be to return a location to a collection containing only those items. It's decidedly suboptimal, which is why I say to prefer PUT or PATCH.